# 9patch (nine-patch) image does not stretch /scale properly

Tags: android, nine-patch

Dear Fellow Developers,

I've ran into the problem shown in the attached picture. We have been trying to tweak the dropdown menu's 9patch image provided by a graphics designer, but could not get it to work. The black stretch markers are not being hidden, and Android does not stretch it the way we would expect.

The device is a Nexus 7. We have tried several various image sizes, but none seemed to work. I am also attaching a copy of the 9patch.

What could be wrong?!

This happens:

[image: The symptom]

[Here is the 9patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b10JJ.png)

Comment: May be something wrong with your 9patch image.

Comment: Does your file have .9.png extension?

Comment: Yes, my file has the .9.png extension.

Answer (score 1):

If the image has been created in a normal image editor rather than the android 9 patch tool, it could be just that its not done exactly right.

The image must have a 1px transparent border other than where the black lines are. Make sure its completely transparent and is only 1 px thick

Also I don't think you can have split lines (like you have down the left and right side of the image, I think they must be one solid line on each side)

Comment: IIRC completely white with no alpha e.g. `0xFFFFFFFF` may also be acceptable for the transparent areas but I'd double check if you intend to go down that route

Comment: Where should the transparent border be? Is it like this: black lines => transparent area => image content? Or like transparent area => black lines => image content?

Comment: No, you can have split lines (up and left). Each black pixel (left and up) indicates a stretchable area, whereas down ad right indicates "content area" (what you leave transparent acts as a "padding")

Comment: My explanation was a bit unclear. Your image needs a 1px border. This is where you put your black lines to mark the stretchable areas. The rest of this border must be transparent or apparently white (I didn't know that!)

Comment: I think this image corresponds to all these requirements, but it still does not stretch...

Comment: You could try taking away the black lines on the right and the bottom - From what I can tell this might give you the stretch you're after